# word_stats function from qdap package application on a dataframe

Tags: r, string, dataframe, qdap

I have a dataframe, where one column contains strings.

```
q = data.frame(number=1:2,text=c("The surcingle hung in ribands from my body.", "But a glance will show the fallacy of this idea."))
```

I want to use the word_stats function for each individual record.
is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
text_statistic <- apply(q,1,word_stats)
```

this will apply `word_stats()` row-by-row and return a list with the results of `word_stats()` for every row

Answer (score 0):

you can do it many ways, `lapply` or `sapply` apply a Function over a List or Vector.

`word_stats <- function(x) {length(unlist(strsplit(x, ' ')))}
sapply(q$text, word_stats)`

Answer (score 0):

Sure have a look at the `grouping.var` argument:

```
dat = data.frame(number=1:2,text=c("The surcingle hung in ribands from my body.", "But a glance will show the fallacy of this idea."))


with(dat, qdap::word_stats(text, number))

##   number n.sent n.words n.char n.syl n.poly wps cps sps psps   cpw   spw pspw n.state p.state n.hapax grow.rate
## 1 2           1      10     38    14      2  10  38  14    2 3.800 1.400 .200       1       1      10         1
## 2 1           1       8     35    12      1   8  35  12    1 4.375 1.500 .125       1       1       8         1
```